# How to automatically extend the tab control as items are added to it without creating a scroll bar?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I am using a WPF user control (tab control) to add tab items dynamically in the simplified code below:

```
....
foreach (string id in ids)
{
    TabControl.Items.Add(CreateTabItem(id));
}

private TabItem CreateTabItem(string name)
{
    StackPanel txtBlock = new TextBlock();
    txtblock.Text = name;
    txtBlock.HorizontalAlignment = Horizontalalignment.Center;
    panel.Children.Add(txtBlock);

    TabItem item = new TabItem();
    item.Header = panel;

    <SomeControl> control = new <SomeControl>();
    item.Content = control;
    return item;
 }
```

In the xaml file I specified the following to stack all my tab items to the left column:

```
MinWidth="100" MinHeight="300" TabStripPlacement="Left"
```

How do I make my tab control automatically extending (ie. stretching) its height to show all the tab items as I add them in?  For now, I have to manually extend the height of the display window to see all the tab items.  Your insights/tips are greatly appreciated.

PS:  if you know how to make the vertical scroll bar appears (without adding scroll bar to my control) as soon as the tab items exceed the window height, I can settle for that if there are no answers for my original intent.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the tab strip to get bigger? For example, if you pace the tab strip to the left, do you want strip to get wider (start a 2nd column) after it reaches the bottom?

Comment: No i just want to scroll the left column part of my control where i stacked the tab icons vertically.  The remaining part of my control should stay within view when i scroll the left column. I am still thinking of a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <TabControl
        TabStripPlacement="Left"
        x:Name="Tab"
    >
    </TabControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

gets you the scrollbar which will be enabled when needed.

Comment: Thanks Donnelle.  It turned out that the scrollviewer is not what i want because it scrolled everything on my control out of view NOT just the left column where i stacked the tab icons.  I'm still thinking of a way to scroll just the left column (ie; grid column) on my control.

Comment: So are you looking to have scrolling functionality like Firefox's tabs, except that you want the scrollbar to advance to the next row of tabs, rather than scroll one tab at a time horizontally?